# Excel Power Query How to Add in Source Name

Tags: excel, powerquery

Say I have three worksheets as input sources.
How do i add the name of the sheet within PowerQuery so that when i combine all the sheets i can see the name of the sheet and know which sheet the data came from.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not understanding what you want. Could you post some sample workbooks and/or screenshots showing what it should look like?

Comment: Example - on each sheet i have two columns with data - COL A, COL B. How do i get access to the sheet name in PowerQuery so that i can have 3 cols in the data SHEET_NAME, COL A, COL B. Then when i merge the queries i can see which sheet a specific row came from. Presently I am setting a string literal in a custom column for the sheet name but I think there must be a way of accessing the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering all sheets are of the same structure:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("PATH\FILE.xlsx"), null, true),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Name", "Data"}),
    #"Promote Headers" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Data", Table.PromoteHeaders}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Promote Headers", "Data", {"ColA", "ColB"}, {"ColA", "ColB"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"
```

If you have other named objects in your workbooks, add filter after `Source` step to get only what you need.